Denial of entry to country: any insurance for this?
In Bulgaria recently they have started cracking down on Visa C (tourist visas, business visas). Meaning you don't just need your visa, you need documentation proving the requirements for the visa, such as funds, reservations, etc.
I have students, who are from India, who come to Bulgaria to get some courses in very specific things.
The school wants me to pay upfront and take the risk, which for 10 students is like 10.000€.
I found solutions for the plane tickets, accomodation, that can be canelled, but how do I insure for the school course?
Is there such a travel insurance that covers something like this?
I am talking about denial of entry when you are already in the country, not denial of visa whenn you apply.
Having a visa and not being let in should be pretty low risk scenario so insurance for it should exist for it?

if your visa has been granted, surely you have already provided the documentation, so you have it, no?

@njzk2 Having a visa does not entitle you to enter a country.  Technically it is up to whoever is at the border crossing to accept or reject your entry.  As an example, if you show up at a boarder with an already granted tourist visa, but you are carrying stuff that makes it look like you are looking for work, you will be rejected.  It seems like the OP is worried about the chance (albeit very small) that the students entry will be rejected for some reason out of their control.

I’m unclear what your role in this scenario is. An agent organising visas? A business bringing groups of students on study courses? Both? The risk of denial of entry sits with the applicant, why would you take on that risk yourself? In any event I don’t think this type of risk is covered by travel insurance. Get the students to pay you upfront, then you can pay the school.

Your scenario is very specific, and work related (not much travel related). You should ask insurances (or just self-insurance: calculate the risk and a premium, and consider it part of the price of service). I would not take personal responsibility for free, for gain of other people.

@njzk2 yes, but it happens that they turn people away at the border. Just recently a business partner was turned away. Apparently the embassy was more lax.

@Traveller my role is an organizer of courses for foreigners, who want to come to EU to get certain certifications. So Im not sure what that makes me, something like an agency. Since these courses need a translator and are only done for my students, I am expected to pay upfront with no backsies.

@GiacomoCatenazzi if I knew the risk I would self insure as you suggest. But these things just keep changing all the time. Not only the laws but also how closely they are followed, how strict .etc.

@user1721135 Then denial of entry is an inherent risk of the nature of your business and there is no insurance available to cover it. Charge your students upfront is the answer, if not in full at least enough per student to give you a buffer against a couple of them being denied entry.
